# Titanium android data reflection in table view

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Google APIs Android 2.3.1 , data changes in the database tables not reflecting in tableview screens, but if we restart the app, will show changes and also, if we load app.js will show recent changes.

Can anyone help me to fix this??

```
fireEvent("db_update")
```

&
  addEventListener('db_update', function() {  what should be here to update table data })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('updatedb', updateData);
```

here 'updateData' is the function which gets the data for tableview from the databae. At the 
bottom of 'updateData' function, set data for table view

```
i.e)   tableview.setData(data);
```

and then, your insert, update or delete function should trigger 'updatedb' function

i.e)

```
function deleteData(recId)  {
    var db = Ti.Database.open(DBNAME);
        db.execute(" DELETE FROM tblName WHERE id IN("+ recId+") ");
        db.close();

    Ti.App.fireEvent('dataupdated');
}
```

now, after calling deleteData function, your tableview data will show w/o deleted record.

Answer (score 0):

For updating a database, you need to remove it first, and then install a new one. Or run queries to update the current one.

This is how I update my database, based on a version number I store in the properties:

```
function updateDatabase(version){
    if (version != Ti.App.Properties.getInt('version',0)){
        sb.db.remove();
        sb.db = Ti.Database.install('/lib/db.sqlite','db');
        Ti.App.Properties.setInt('version',version);
    }
}
```

In the app, on start, I run the function with a manual typed version number in it. Every time your database changes you can manually change this number.

```
updateDatabase(5);
```

This of course does not reflect a regular update on the content of a table. (when you run a regular query on the database).

In that case, you should rebuild the content of the tableview yourself (you have the code to fill the tableview, rerun that code) or find a way to target the exact row you need to change with an ID for example.